# Linux headers missing from a custom kernel built through cross-compilation

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, kernel, cross-compilation

Helo,

I have followed the instructions given at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md to build a custom kernel. (I have cross-compiled it on an x86 box.) The custom kernel is running perfectly under Raspbian on a RPI 3B+.

The cross-compilation process has not generated a linux-headers-VERSION.deb package.

How do I install the Kernel Headers for this custom kernel? (I need them to compile a kernel loadable module.)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

- The headers should usually be installed using `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers –y`

  You'll see the headers installed at `/usr/src`
- If you don't see the headers that correspond to your current kernel source `uname -r`:

Install dependencies for [`rpi-source`](https://github.com/RPI-Distro/rpi-source)

```
sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev
```

Install your rpi-source

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && /usr/local/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update
```

Run

```
rpi-source
```

After this you'll see two folders. One of them is a symbolic link to the other named `linux-{sha-number to git commit pointing to kernel version}`. e.g. `linux-1f9874a5435d6c3fd94a2ad00823d85cb59fc0b4`

Move this folder to /usr/src/ where kernel headers should be located on your Raspberry Pi and rename it `linux`:

```
sudo mv linux-{sha-number} /usr/src/linux
```

Create symbolic links after removing the ones created by rpi-source in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`:

```
cd /usr/src
sudo ln -s linux linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r/source
```

Let me know if this works and if there's a better way of course

Comment: Use https://github.com/RPI-Distro/rpi-source to get the current source for your kernel.

Comment: That works out too. I'll update this answer